# Angular 6 kendo-dropdownlist ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using a searchable kendo-dropdownlist in my HTML. If value is selected in dropdown the code works fine. However, if nothing is selected, I get error in Chrome developer tools as:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #projDetails="ngForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Approver">Approver</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="IdData"
                                            [textField]="'text'"
                                            [valueField]="'value'"
                                            [filterable]="true"
                                            (valueChange)="valueChange($event)"
                                            (filterChange)="filterChange($event)"
                                            [(ngModel)]="SelectedIdItem"
                                            name="SelectedIdItem"
                                            [popupSettings]="{ height: 300, width: 300 }"
                                            #SelectedIdItemControl="ngModel"
                                            required
                                            title="Start typing to search">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="SubmitDetails(projDetails);">Submit></button>
```

Here is component class, Submit button click:

```
   public SubmitDetails(form: NgForm) {
        var dataProjDetail = {
            'Id': form.value.SelectedIdItem.value == undefined ? null : form.value.SelectedIdItem.value 

        };

        //passing data to service
    }
```

I tried checking the undefined value and replace by null using

```
form.value.SelectedIdItem.value == undefined ? null : form.value.SelectedIdItem.value
```

But still does not work. Please guide how to handle the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, looks everything ok. Of course, value is not a attribute both undefined and null. But we can use `<button [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">Submit</button>` or

```
SubmitDetails(form: ngForm) {
  if (! form.valid) return;
  ...
}
```

reject the bad data before submit. Usually the formGroup used, so I can't sure ngForm.valid is ok, but same logic there.